# Is voting supposed to be permitted on answers to closed questions?

Tags: support, voting, closed-questions

Votes have come in on my answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022741/plzz-can-u-help-me/2022752#2022752) after it was closed. I might deserve them, but it seems a bit odd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Closing (or indeed locking) a question doesn't prevent voting on answers. It doesn't even prevent voting on the question (although locking does).

If we *lock* individual / all answers (very rare), then *that* prevents voting.

This is by design. Just because something was closed as "no longer relevant", for example, doesn't mean that the answers were without merit; let 'em get their dues. In the "not a real question" example, it may be that you were able to infer enough from the question to give a good answer. Indeed, there is even a badge for great answers on downvoted questions (downvoted questions and closed questions have a large overlap).